# how to correctly display elements when API fetch returning HTML special entities (such as &quot)?

Tags: html, reactjs, api

I am fetching data from a trivia api, however the data I am retrieving is not in a format where I can readily display it, is there a problem with how I am fetching / storing the data? what is an easy fix?

Fetching & storing

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=medium")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(info => setData(info.results.map(item => {
        return { 
          type: item.type, 
          question: item.question, 
          correct_answer: item.correct_answer, 
          incorrect_answers: item.incorrect_answers,
          id: nanoid() 
        }})))
  }, [])
```

An example of how the raw data is currently being displayed

```
{
    "type": "multiple",
    "question": "What is the German word for &quot;spoon&quot;?",
    "correct_answer": "L&ouml;ffel",
    "incorrect_answers": [
      "Gabel",
      "Messer",
      "Essst&auml;bchen"
    ],
    "id": "8IfTTvpoQd8DaJ1Hx941a"
  },
```

as can see from above it is displaying the data as its raw special entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the package 'he' by following command

> npm install he

in js

```
import { decode } from 'he';

const json = {
    type: 'multiple',
    question: 'What is the German word for &quot;spoon&quot;?',
    correct_answer: 'L&ouml;ffel',
    incorrect_answers: ['Gabel', 'Messer', 'Essst&Auml;bchen'],
    id: '8IfTTvpoQd8DaJ1Hx941a',
};
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(json, null, 4);
const decodedString = decode(jsonString)
```

in your HTML

```
<pre>
   <code>{decodedString}</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: That did the trick!